# How to use SIGINT for threads C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, sigint

I am trying to use SIGINT (CNTRL C) for threads but it is having a weird behavior. I am trying to have a SIGINT function for the thread creator process and a SIGINT function for the threads themselves. Here is a sample code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_t *cars;
 

void carEnd(){
  printf("Car from team %ld killed.\n",(long)getpid());
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void teamEnd(int signum){
  for(int j=0; j<3; j++){

    pthread_join(cars[j],NULL);
  }

  printf("Team %ld killed\n",(long)getpid());
  exit(0);
}

void *carThread(void* team_number){
  signal(SIGINT, carEnd);
  sleep(10);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return NULL;

}

int main(){
  signal(SIGINT, teamEnd);

  int workerId[3];

  pthread_t cars[3];

  //Create the car threads
  for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
    workerId[i] = i+1;
    pthread_create(&cars[i], NULL, carThread,&workerId[i]);
  }
  //Waits for all the cars to die
  for(int j=0; 3; j++){
    pthread_join(cars[j],NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
`
```

After executing, if no SIGINT is detected the program closes after 10 seconds. If a SIGINT is detected, then a single message "Car from team ... killed" appears on the terminal. Would appreciate if anyone could  explain me this behavior and how I can fix it to achieve my goal!

Comment: Signals is a *process* thing mainly. Only a few signals can be sent to specific threads. The vast majority of signals will be sent to a randomly selected thread in the process.

Comment: I guess [`pthread_cancel`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) might interest you instead?

Comment: Also, how are you sending `SIGINT` to a thread?

Comment: You should probably enable compiler warnings. Also, I'd recommend learning the basics of C before attempting to use *either* signals or threads. Using *both* signals and threads at the same time is something that I would recommend trying to avoid at all cost.

Comment: Also, on POSIX systems you can only make async-signal-safe function calls from within a signal handler.  Neither `printf()` nor `pthread_join()` are async-signal-safe.  (In strictly-conforming C code, you can't call **any** C library functions...)

Answer (score 1):

A <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> instructs your terminal to send a SIGINT to the foreground process group, meaning a SIGINT is generated for each process of the foreground group.

When a signal is generated for a process, the system attempts to deliver it to *one and only one thread* of that process.  In your example, all of your threads are eligible to receive the signal, since none have masked ("blocked") the signal as by [`pthread_sigmask`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html).  The system will choose one of the threads for signal delivery.

When the SIGINT is delivered to a thread, some action, known as the signal disposition, is taken.  Importantly, a process can have one and only one disposition per signal at any given time — the most recent call to `signal()` or [`sigaction`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) determines the disposition.  So, your `main()` thread's chosen SIGINT disposition of `teamEnd()` is overwritten by the first of your `carThread()` threads to call `signal()`, and then redundantly overwritten by the rest of them.

In your case, the SIGINT happens to interrupt a `carThread()` during its `sleep()`, printing the message you see, and waking the thread which then terminates.

---

Beyond the above, I cannot really say what you should do.  I *think* your goal is to gracefully terminate all threads upon SIGINT.  If that's so, I'd suggest you do that by forcing the signal to be delivered to `main()`, and then having that thread instruct the others to quit via some shared flag or condition variable.